# How to return a json response in one line in flask?

Tags: python, json, flask, jsonify

I am coding a route in flask to send this response and I need to send this json response in a single solid line but when I send this json(because of length) send in multiple line

```
@app.route("/dashboard", methods= ['GET','POST'])
def index():
.
.
.
response = {"iDisplayStart":1,"iDisplayLength":10,
"iTotalRecords":2,"iTotalDisplayRecords":2,"data":data_ne}

return jsonify(results)
```

when I send this json response  return below

```
 {
  "iDisplayStart": 1, 
  "iDisplayLength": 10, 
  "iTotalRecords": 2, 
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": 2, 
  "data": [
  {data_ne}]}
```

but I want to be in single line like below

```
  {"iDisplayStart":1,"iDisplayLength":10,"iTotalRecords":2,"iTotalDisplayRecords":2,"data":data_ne}
```

Is there any way to do this? Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: why single line is important?

Comment: @balderman 
I don't know exactly I try to work with a code (html , jQuery , ajax) that I'm unfamiliar with them and I know when  send response in a solid single line that code worked

Comment: I don't think it has ANY importance..

Comment: @balderman
you are right, I test and don't work again may I look deeper in code and something is unusual is when send exactly this response but in ' '(string mode) that code worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running Flask in debug mode? Try setting `JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR` environment variable to false. From the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#module-flask.json):

> The default output omits indents and spaces after separators. In debug mode or if JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR is True, the output will be formatted to be easier to read.